# How to get data between a date range in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a problem. I have taken `date` column in `varchar(10)` formate and `date` is stored as `23-May-2015` format.

Now I want to get all rows between dates `23-May-2015` and `02-June-2015`.

How can I get all rows in between both dates.

I have tried to use this query

```
SELECT `custid`
FROM `milkdet`
WHERE `date`>='.$stdate.' AND `date`<='.$enddate.'
GROUP BY `custid`
ORDER BY `date`
```

but it's not working.

PS : I have done this only for learning that how this thing is possible.

Comment: I doubt that your value is actually saved into db

Comment: Varchar(10)? How would that work? Anyway, store dates using the appropriate data type. Then get back to us.

Comment: values are in format 24-May-2015

Comment: You should not save dates as varchar. You should save it in a column of type date

Comment: Plainly, that's not true. Your string is more than 10 characters in length. Anyway, see above.

Comment: @Strawberry I have written that it is only for learning I want to know if anytime this problem occurs then how can we rid off

Comment: If you have saved that date within database then it might be saved as `23-May-201` not `23-May-2015`

Comment: @lord_linus OK, well you have an answer below.

Comment: why you are strict to save date in this format? dates should be saved in proper mysql database format like yyyy-mm-dd. So you can use strtotime() function in php to convert dates in different format, but in database values should be saved in date format.

Comment: Mysql 'knows' about `date` and `times` and has data types specifically for them. It is suggested that you always use them. You can always format them  on output into any format you want. see: [11.3.1 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 4):

`varchar()` dates are evil and you should store date using mysql native datatypes.

In your case you first need to convert the dates into real date using `str_to_date` function as

```
mysql> select str_to_date('23-May-2015','%d-%M-%Y') as d ;
+------------+
| d          |
+------------+
| 2015-05-23 |
+------------+
```

Now in the query you will have

```
select `custid`
from `milkdet` 
where str_to_date(`date`, '%d-%M-%Y') >= str_to_date('$stdate','%d-%M-%Y')
AND str_to_date(`date`, '%d-%M-%Y') <=str_to_date('$enddate','%d-%M-%Y')
group by `custid` 
order by `date`
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT  * FROM `milkdet` WHERE `date` >= '2015-05-23 00:00:00' 
AND `date` <= '2015-06-02 00:00:00'
```

Comment: It is very helpful to provide some explanation in your answer.